# how to clear powershell history without creating a new version of the file?

Tags: windows, powershell

On linux I use this command to delete the commands i run:

```
  whoami && id && hostname; history -d $(history 1)
```

I would like to do the same thing on windows but for powershell..
So for each powershell command I run, how do I delete the relative saved string inside the HistorySavePath of PSreadline, without writing a new version of ConsoleHost_history.txt, using the same method I use on linux?

ps: I'm not looking for a solution to clear the whole history, or to manually editing the text file with notepad.

@@EDIT:

I may have a solution, but i don't know how to apply that. one trick would be to read the content of ConsoleHost_history.txt, store it in memory, and overwrite the content ( so i won't create a new file )  with the one stored BUT without the last command I ran

@@EDIT2:

i need also to clean the Get-History part rather than just PSreadline hist file. if i run ' command; Clear-History -Count 1 -Newest ' it does not actually work:

```
 184 hostname; Clear-History -Count 1 -Newest
 185 Get-History
```

How can make it work all in oneline?

Comment: You can use `Clear-History -Count 1 -Newest` BUT: 1) `Clear-History` itself will be visible (if you mimic the Linux command using `;`), 2) the _gap_ will be visible inspecting the ID, 3) this won't clear the `PSReadLine` module history so those commands are still available in the console using arrow keys (for example)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti thanks! i already know about clear-history, i'm looking for a specific solution about ConsoleHost_history.txt. as you said, clear-history won't affect that file

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti ps: i tried out of curiosity 'whoami; Clear-History -Count 1 -Newest'.. that is interesting ( even if does not fit my case ), but seems that it adds just an empty line ( the missign IDs ) between the commands, it does not actually delete the commands:  65 whoami; Clear-History -Count 1 -Newest 67 dir; Clear-History -Count 1 -Newest

Comment:  it's a bit unexpected (at least to me). It won't solve your problem (sorry) but the easiest way to workaround `Clear-History` is probably to do it within a do-nothing cmdlet. It won't work with `;` but `End {}` for a cmdlet should be executed _after_ the history has been updated (might be the way to go also to trim the last line in `ConsoleHost_history.txt` but I'm not sure how reliable it is). Something like `Secret-Command | Remove-LastCommandInHistory` (definitely not a one-off thing...)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti don't be sorry, you are helping me!(: btw... seems like i actually need also to find a solution to make ' command; Clear-History -Count 1 -Newest' work somehow..

Comment: You could try to write your own cmdlet which simply pipes its input to the output (`Process { $my_input }`) and it _plays_ with the history like in `End { Clear-History -Count 1 -Newest }` (or something like that...)

Answer (score 0):

**Deletes entries from the PowerShell session command history.**

```
Clear-History
     [[-Id] <int[]>]
     [[-Count] <int>]
     [-Newest]
     [-WhatIf]
     [-Confirm]
     [<CommonParameters>]


Clear-History
     [[-Count] <int>]
     [-CommandLine <string[]>]
     [-Newest]
     [-WhatIf]
     [-Confirm]
     [<CommonParameters>]
```

Description

Clear-History deletes the command history from a PowerShell session. Each PowerShell session has its own command history. To display the command history, use the Get-History cmdlet.

By default, Clear-History deletes the entire command history from a PowerShell session. You can use parameters with Clear-History to delete selected commands.

Clear-History does not clear the PSReadLine command history file. The PSReadLine module stores a history file that contains every PowerShell command from every PowerShell session. From a PowerShell prompt, use the up and down arrows on your keyboard to scroll through the command history. To display the PSReadLine configuration for command history, use Get-PSReadLineOption. PSReadLine shipped with PowerShell 5.0 and above. For more information, see about_PSReadLine.

**more information follow this link**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/clear-history?view=powershell-7.3